# SQL Generated select menu, updating textbox based on related value

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

**Some Background information:**

- I have a table with two fields, TECHNAME and TECHCOLOR

**What I am trying to do is:**

- Have a SQL generated Drop down menu based on TECHNAME (DONE)
- Have TECHCOLOR update in text box when TECHNAME is selected (ISSUE IS HERE)

**What is wrong**

- Currently, the textbox is showing TECHNAME insead of TECHCOLOR

**Code**

**JavaScript:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function load_value(value)
      {
          document.getElementById("test").value=value;
      }
    </script>
```

**HTML/PHP:**

```
<table>
<form method="post" action="">  
        <?php
        $select_box='<select name="edittech"  id="edittech" onchange="javascript:load_value(this.value);">';
        $input="";
                    $result = $conn->query("select * from techs");
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $select_box .='<option id="name"  value="'.$row["TECHNAME"].'">'.$row['TECHNAME'].'</option>';

        }
    $input ='<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="" />';

echo $select_box."</select>";
echo $input;
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: You need a way to go from TECHNAME to TECHCOLOR. You could generate a JSON string representing a JavaScript object that maps one to the other, then use that to look it up (I don't do PHP, can't tell you what that would look like), you could make an AJAX call to another PHP file that takes TECHNAME as a parameter and returns TECHCOLOR, or (if it's not used anywhere for anything else) you could just make the `value` attribute of each `<option>` element the TECHCOLOR instead of TECHNAME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit the form, is the value for your `edittech` dropdown list used at all? If it isn't then you can simply change the value part of your dropdown to be `TECHCOLOR` and it will still show `TECHNAME` on the dropdown.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $select_box .= "<option id=\"name\" value=\"{$row['TECHCOLOR']}\">{$row['TECHNAME']}</option>";
}
```